# Problem in facebook graph API stream.publish

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-iframe

I am using Graph API and using stream.publish, it was previously working fine but now when I separate JS in a js file then I am passing CANVAS URL as an argument to javascript function, following is my code:

```
function feedPublish(message,image,canvasURL){
var attachment = {'media':[{'type':'image','src':image,'href':canvasURL}]};
var action_links= [{ 'text':"Music Mood", 'href': canvasURL }];
message="I am in mood of "+message;
FB.ui({'method':'stream.publish','message':message,
        'attachment':attachment,
        'action_links':action_links
    },
    function(response){

    }
);  
 }


function publishMessage(message,canvasURL){
   var emo_id='id_'+$('emoction').val();
   var emo_image=$('#'+emo_id+' img.emoction_image').attr('src');
   feedPublish(message,emo_image,canvasURL);
 }
```

then from html I am calling function publish Message on click here:

```
publishMessage('Gimme More (The Legendary Ms. Britney Spears)','http://apps.facebook.com/musicmood'); return false;
```

And getting the following error that is in screenshot[image]:

So I am unable to understand problem, any idea that what's the problem or how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You are using old method for publishing  "stream.publish" please use "feed" method which is included in Graph API
For more details visit this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.ui/

Comment: thanks man but this is not a problem :(, still having same problem

Answer (score 0):

Facebook [says](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/):

> Please note: We are in the process of deprecating the REST API, so if
>   you are building a new application you shouldn't use this function.
>   Instead use the Graph API and POST a Post object to the feed
>   connection of the User object

I would advice you to use the graph api and send a POST request to `/me/feed` with same parameters. It will work.